# Collision detection between two picture boxes not working c# form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Hi I'm working on a game that involves two picture boxes, a red box and a blue box. The blue box is controlled by the player and the goal is to collide with the red box, which teleports to a random location every 5 seconds. My problem is getting a collision between the red and blue box. On collision the red box is to teleport to a random location but that isn't happening.

heres my code:

```
namespace block_game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);

            if (blue_box.Bounds.IntersectsWith(red_box.Bounds))
            {
                Tele();
            }


        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = blue_box.Location.X;
            int y = blue_box.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 10;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 10;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 10;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 10;

            blue_box.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
        public Random r = new Random();
        private void tmrTele_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmrTele.Interval = 5000;
            Tele();
        }

        private void Tele()
        {
            int x = r.Next(0, 800 - red_box.Width);
            int y = r.Next(0, 500 - red_box.Width);
            red_box.Top = y;
            red_box.Left = x;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You only seem to check the collision at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the collision each time a key is pressed.
Try this:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = blue_box.Location.X;
        int y = blue_box.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 10;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 10;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 10;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 10;

        blue_box.Location = new Point(x, y);
        if (blue_box.Bounds.IntersectsWith(red_box.Bounds))
        {
            //your logic to handle the collision 
        }
    }
```

**Note:** A better way would be checking the collision when the red box re positions itself too, as there can be a condition when the red box bangs into the blue one.

```
    private void Tele()
    {
        int x = r.Next(0, 800 - red_box.Width);
        int y = r.Next(0, 500 - red_box.Width);
        red_box.Top = y;
        red_box.Left = x;

        if (blue_box.Bounds.IntersectsWith(red_box.Bounds))
        {
            //your logic to handle the collision 
        }
    }
```